# Is it possible to automatically generate a file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm creating a user snippet in VSCode for my react function component boilerplate with `import styles from './FileName.module.scss'` and I'm wondering if it's possible to create that `FileName.module.scss` either upon creating a `Filename.tsx` file or running that code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [htmlRelatedLinks.openFile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file).

You can use the command in a keybinding or give it a name using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

Add this to your `settings.json` (global or workspace)

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.createModuleSCCS",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
          "args": {
            "file": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.module.sccs",
            "method": "vscode.open"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Edit**

Or you can use the **Related Links** view from the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links)

Add this to your `settings.json`:

```
"html-related-links.include": {
    "typescript": [
      "import .+? from '([^']+)'"
    ]
  }
```

You might need to change the languageId as used for `.tsx` files.

In the **Related Links** view (Explorer Bar) you can click on the **Open File or Create File** icon.